# echo command doesn't work with PowerShell in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, go, terminal, installation

So I'm trying to install golang in my new laptop that has Windows 10 installed in, I was trying to make sure that the working path is correct by `echo $GOPATH` but it doesn't return anything, and it only return the home path if I typed `echo $HOME`

I used `set GOPATH=/User/folder/path` to set the path, is there anything wrong I am doing? or is there any missing files or something in the new laptop?

Comment: try `[environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('GOPATH')`

Comment: Why the `linux` tag when your question is about Windows?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like GOPATH is an environment variable, not a variable like `$HOME`. In powershell, you can access environment variables like this:

```
$env:GOPATH
```